# How can I open tslint.json to edit it?

Tags: visual-studio-code, tslint

In VScode we often talk about editing configuration files to adapt them to our needs. 
But how the heck do you open them to edit them? In particular I would like to open `tslint.json` to add this line:

```
"ordered-imports": [true, {
  "import-sources-order": "any",
  "named-imports-order": "case-insensitive"
}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say to click on it, unless I'm missing something in your question.

[image]